# Por qué tengo este error en mi hosting?

Tags: php, hosting, localhost

la siguiente más que código (PHP), es una pregunta que me está pasando y es algo muy curioso, pero necesito saber si alguien sabe algo sobre este tema.

Resulta que tengo una página de registro de usuarios y al registrarse se crea una carpeta para dicha persona en el servidor, pero cuando el usuario desea cambiar o actualizar la imagen de perfil, se crea otra carpeta como la anterior y guarda la imagen en una de estas y la otra queda vacía, esto en mí servidor local no lo hacia pero lo subí a un hosting de pago y me genera esta curiosidad.

A alguno le ha pasado estó? Qué puede ser?
Cualquier cosa que sepan por favor me pueden ayudar.

PD: el código esta bien, lo he probado en local y funciona muy bien, inclusive hasta ayer lo estube probando en el hosting y servía de las mil maravillas, hoy no se que paso, y lo cambie por el del local y hace lo mismo.

Comment: Comprueba versión de php si difiere. Por otra parte podrías comprobar si la carpeta existe y si no existe crearla y si existe no crearla.

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, ya verifique la versión que usan en el hosting y es la misma que uso en local, y respecto a la desición (if), esa opción se hace, además la carpeta ya está creada con anterioridad y cuando actualiza la foto la ruta esta dentro de la carpeta, lo raro como decía anteriormente es que en local (en mi localhost) no pasa eso como en el hosting esta sucediendo.

Comment: habría que ver código o al menos saber cómo son los nombres de las carpetas